# nodejs default doc on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, installation, ubuntu-12.04, web-deployment

I'm entering new territory here. Not a linux guy at all, but I acquired a dedicated server from my hosting company, Ubuntu 12.0.4 running apache2. I have my domain name that successfully resolves to that server (basic html 'Hello World' index page shows up fine).

I've installed npm, node and express and they are (far as I can tell) working properly. I've added this app to the root as 'hello.js':

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.write("Hello World");
    res.end();
  });

  app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server Started");
  });
```

After i putty in (term?) and run 'node hello.js' I get the 'Server Started' message. But no results when I go to my domain. If I have an index.html page, I get it's contents. If I remove it, I get a dir listing.

How do make hello.js the sites default doc? Or, more generally, how do I set entry points to run node sites on a lve server with this config? I can write node, but deploying is turning out to be quite a bit harder than expected. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's `process.env.PORT`? Find out by `console.log(process.env.PORT)`. Maybe you need to `app.listen(` ***`80`*** `, function...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of hitting Apache.  Not your Node.js server.

Try starting your server like this from the command line:

```
$ PORT=8080 node hello.js
```

Then point your browser to:

```
http://www.youdomain.com:8080/
```

That will start your node.js process on port 8080.  The first argument to app.listen is `process.env.PORT` which is an environment variable that you're setting on the command line with the command above.

This should work so long as you don't have port 8080 blocked in a firewall between your server and your local machine.

If you want Node.js to power your whole web site on the standard port 80 then you'll need to disable Apache first or set it up as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Sure. What I'm trying to figure out is how to I have node handle requests for certain documents/sites. I'm a noob at linux/apache but understood this to be a not terribly difficult thing to do. Node is functioning on the site (console responds when I start the server). How do I get requests to route to node as opposed to apache?

Comment: Ooops! You comment only had first line when I refreshed, sorry!

Comment: But yes, I'd like node to power the entire site (the reason I acquired the server in the first place, I basically want a live sandbox). Which route would you recommend, disable apache or reverse proxy?

Comment: If you just want to use node for your entire site then you'll need to disable Apache and then you can run node on port 80.

Comment: I apologize, I'm really a complete noob on the linux server end. Is there a simple command I can disable apache with? And after that, will process.env.PORT by default handle node requests on port 80? or do I still need to manually set the node listening port to 80? Will that then pick up the 'main' property from package.json and run that file as the default doc? I really can't connect the dots here, trying to do it completely backwards I know! The end goal is just a personal site under my doman name on this server which I can run node apps within :(

Comment: try this: `sudo service apache2 stop`.  Your node process wont automatically start as port 80.  You could change that in the code, but in the mean time you can just do `PORT=80 sudo node hello.js`.  `sudo` allows you to run commands as the root user, which in this case is necessary to listen on port 80 (or any port below 1024).

Comment: Actually, that command for node should have the sudo first.  So `sudo PORT=80 node hello.js`

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Sorry for the slow response, but stopping apache and manually listening on port 80 is working great for me right now. I'll fix the config to eliminate that second step when I get more comfortable with ubuntu.